# HTTP Status 404 - /elecMaven/system/actingIndex.jsp, But my config is correct

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2, http-status-code-404

The error information is below:

> HTTP Status 404 - /elecMaven/system/actingIndex.jsp
>
> type Status report
>
> message /elecMaven/system/actingIndex.jsp
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.75

I have a ztree, and the `menuData.js` is correct:

Part of my `menuData.js`, you can see the url is struts action, not a path:

```
   {
        mid:'ap',
        pid:'am',
        name:'运行监控',
        icon:'../images/MenuIcon/daibanshiyi.gif',
        target:'mainFrame',
        url:'${pageContext.request.contextPth}/system/elecCommonMsgAction_home.do',
        isParent:false
    }
```

The `menuData.js` is inclued by `left.jsp`(You can find it at the below image)

In my `struts.xml`:

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do"></constant>
...

<package name="system" namespace="/system" extends="struts-default">
    ......
    <action name="elecCommonMsgAction_*" class="elecCommonMsgAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="home">/WEB-INF/page/system/actingIndex.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And the location of `actingIndex.jsp` is here:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Why I get the 404 error?

---

In my `ElecCommonMsgAction.java`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Controller("elecCommonMsgAction")
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class ElecCommonMsgAction extends BaseAction<ElecCommonMsg> {

    ElecCommonMsg elecCommonMsg = this.getModel();
    // Service
    @Resource(name = IElecCommonMsgService.SERVICE_NAME)
    IElecCommonMsgService elecCommonMsgService;

    /**
     *
     * @return 跳转到actingIndex.jsp
     */
    public String home() {

        ElecCommonMsg elecCommonMsg1 = elecCommonMsgService.findElecCommonMsg();

        ValueUtils.putValueStack(elecCommonMsg1);

        return "home";
    }

}
```

At this line:

```
public String home() {
```

I take a breakpoint, when test, it did not come in there.

---

**Update**:

The location of `struts.xml`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Have you configured Struts to accept `.do` extension?

Comment: What is the location of `struts.xml`?

Comment: @RomanC I update my post, you can see the location of `struts.xml`.

Comment: @AleksandrM I update my post, and you can see the extension config in my `struts.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it is true, last night I can not solve the issue, then close my laptop and fall in sleep, today I wake up, and re-start my macbook pro, and find it become normal.

So I think my solution is restart my computer.